# SAP Hana dynamic query

Tags: hana

Hi I have query in sql which I am trying to convert in HANA as I am new to HANA I am not able to get this conversion can any one help will be big help I tried for couple of hours but no luck any help will be appreciated 
Here  is my SQL version of the Query

```
DECLARE @UDTNameVar nvarchar(30)
DECLARE @UDTCodeVar nvarchar(30)
SET @UDTNameVar = [%UDTName];
SET @UDTCodeVar = [%UDTCode];


DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX)

SET @SQL = 'SELECT Code FROM [' + @UDTNameVar+ '] WHERE Code = ''' + @UDTCodeVar + '''' 
exec sp_executesql @SQL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE UDTNameVar nvarchar(30);
DECLARE UDTCodeVar nvarchar(30);
DECLARE SQLtext nvarchar(4000);

UDTNameVar := '[%UDTName]'; --maybe the ' is not needed, check and please confirm
UDTCodeVar := '[%UDTCode]';

SQLtext := 'SELECT Code FROM "' || :UDTNameVar || '" WHERE Code = ''' || :UDTCodeVar || '''';

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :SQLtext;
```

This should work, you could check it on HANA Studio to make sure it gets exactly what you need.
Remember to declare all together and use the `:=` instead of `SET` and `||` instead of `+`, also use `;` at the end of each line.